# Запятые перед "и" в сложном предложении. Есть ли общее слово?

Tags: пунктуация, и

Есть такое предложение: "Если я не убивал тех четверых, и ты не убивал их, и он не делал этого, тогда кто?"

Вопрос в том, нужны ли здесь запятые перед "и"? С одной стороны, есть общее слово "если". С другой стороны, смущает тот факт, что здесь аж три предложения!
Правильна ли пунктуация?

Comment: Вам бы следовало изменить заголовок. Вы приняли ответ, в котором утверждается, что нет общего слова.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я не убивал тех четверых, и (если) ты не убивал их, и (если) он не делал этого, тогда кто?

**Все запятые на месте, интонация перечислительная.**

Это три однородных придаточных (два союза ЕСЛИ пропущены), но союз И - **повторяющийся** (хотя бы два раза), поэтому запятые ставятся.

(Союз ЕСЛИ нельзя считать общим элементом.)